# nvd3 - Required Help in Converting Data for Stacked Area Chart

Tags: jquery, html, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need help in converting a flat data to be used to used for the nvd3 Stacked Area Chart from the website mentioned - [Stacked Area Chart - NVD3.JS](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html).

**Sample Data :**

```
levels 01-Oct-13    02-Oct-13   03-Oct-13
level1      11        13            13
level2      11        20            20
level3      17        11            11
level4      10        20            20
level5      15        18            18
level6      12        15            15
level7      17        17            17
```

**Required Format :**

```
    [
        {
        "key": "level1"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 11], [ 1141102800000 , 13], [[ 1141102800000 , 13]]
        },
        {
        "key": "level2"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 11], [ 1141102800000 , 20], [[ 1141102800000 , 20]]
        },
        {
        "key": "level3"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 17], [ 1141102800000 , 11], [[ 1141102800000 , 11]]
        },
        {
        "key": "level4"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 10], [ 1141102800000 , 20], [[ 1141102800000 , 20]]
        },
        "key": "level5"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 11], [ 1141102800000 , 13], [[ 1141102800000 , 13]]
        },
        {
        "key": "level6"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 11], [ 1141102800000 , 13], [[ 1141102800000 , 13]]
        },
        "key": "level7"
        "values" : [[1138683600000, 11], [ 1141102800000 , 13], [[ 1141102800000 , 13]]
        }
    ]
```

Tried using d3.nest() function but i couldn't get the in the format requried.

Would like to take some suggestions on converting the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out on how to convert the data. used d3.nest with map and i got the data in the desired format. Detailed info in the following like as it may be helpful. [**Converting Flat Data to NVD3**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701359/d3-convert-strings-to-actual-values)