# d3 - convert strings to actual values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Please help me in convert in the below strings to actual data.

```
    [
      {
        "key": "model1",
        "values": [
          "[1001874600000,16]",
          "[1001961000000,11]",
          "[1002047400000,14]",
          "[1002133800000,19]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "model2",
        "values": [
          "[1001874600000,14]",
          "[1001961000000,18]",
          "[1002047400000,14]",
          "[1002133800000,12]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "model3",
        "values": [
          "[1001874600000,14]",
          "[1001961000000,13]",
          "[1002047400000,11]",
          "[1002133800000,20]"
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "model4",
        "values": [
          "[1001874600000,11]",
          "[1001961000000,11]",
          "[1002047400000,17]",
          "[1002133800000,11]"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I used the below function to convert a flat data to the above format.

```
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d){
            d.count = +d.count;
            d.date = Date.parse(d.date);
        });

        var nest = d3.nest()
            .key(function(d) {return d.model;})
            .rollup(function(v) {return v.map(function(d) {return "[" + d.date + "," + d.count + "]";})})
            .entries(data)



        d3.select('body').append('pre')
                   .text(JSON.stringify(nest, null, '  '));
        });
```

Now i just need to remove the double quotes in the values field. Some one please help me in this, I don't have any clue on how to do it.

Help will be much pleased.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, `eval` is evil, but you can use it to convert your strings to lists like so:

```
var data = '[1,2,3]';
data = eval(data); // returns [1,2,3]
```

Or you can rewrite the following `return` statement

```
return "[" + d.date + "," + d.count + "]";
```

like so

```
return [d.date, d.count];
```

Comment: Dude - Thanks a lot. That made be to be free. Thanks again!!

Comment: @user2549787 you're welcome. :) please, accept my answer by clicking on the tick button, if it helped you.

Comment: There it goes!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly on topic, but there is something that anyone reading this should be aware of. You should stay as far away from the eval() function unless you 100%, and I can't stress the 100% enough, know the incoming data (i.e. not coming from another source and controlled by you).

Here is some reading to help provide more details ([what are the issues javascript eval can pose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607539/what-are-the-issues-javascript-eval-can-pose)).